# Class that subclasses PFObject and conforms to JSQMessageData

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I currently have a `JSQMessagesViewController`, but am running to the problem of storing my `JSQMessages` in Parse.com, since Parse.com won't allow this type of object. I've been trying to research ways of creating a class that subclasses `PFObject` while conforming to  `JSQMessageData` so that I can create messages that are of type `PFObject` and thus able to be stored in Parse.com.

Below is my `Messages` class. In my `JSQMessagesViewController` I would typically call

```
    var newMessage = JSQMessage(senderId: "user", displayName: "user", text: "testing chat")
```

But now how would I do this with my `Messages` class?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Parse

class Message: PFObject, PFSubclassing, JSQMessageData {
    var senderId_ : String!
    var senderDisplayName_ : String!
    var date_ : NSDate
    var isMediaMessage_ : Bool
    var hash_ : Int = 0
    var text_ : String


    override class func initialize() {
        var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }

    class func parseClassName() -> String {
            return "Messages"
        }

    convenience init(senderId: String?, text: String?) {
        self.init(senderId: senderId!, senderDisplayName: senderId, isMediaMessage: false, hash: 0, text: text!)
    }

    init(senderId: String, senderDisplayName: String?, isMediaMessage: Bool, hash: Int, text: String) {

            self.senderId_ = senderId
            self.senderDisplayName_ = senderDisplayName
            self.date_ = NSDate()
            self.isMediaMessage_ = isMediaMessage
            self.hash_ = hash
            self.text_ = text
            super.init()

        }

    func senderId() -> String? {
            return senderId_;
        }

    func senderDisplayName() -> String? {
            return senderDisplayName_;
        }

    func date() -> NSDate? {
            return date_;
        }

    func isMediaMessage() -> Bool {
                return isMediaMessage_;
        }

    func hash() -> UInt? {
        return UInt(hash_);
    }


    func text() -> String! {
        return text_;
    }

    func messageHash() -> UInt {
        return UInt(hash_)
    }
}
```

And my implementation in my `ChatView` that is a `JSQMessagesViewController`:

```
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var myObject = PFObject(className: "messages")
        var myMessage = Message(senderId: "User", text: "Some text")
        var messageArray:NSMutableArray = [myMessage]
        myObject["myArray"] = messageArray
        myObject.save()
   }
```

Currently receiving error

```
fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class Message
```

Comment: Why you talk about subclassing, when JSQMessageData is protocol?

Comment: Updated to "conforms to JSQMessageData"

Comment: Ok. Maybe your delegate implementation can causing problem.Can you post it?

Comment: Sure thing, updated with implementation and error

Comment: Hi, this looks like a specific Swift problem and I'n not an expert on it, but from what I saw you call super.init() on init with parameters, and that can cause a problems. Check this document: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html

Comment: @KyleH: Have you found any solution ?